# ASP .Net Core: how to input collection of data of different types

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to set up the data I input on ASP.Net Core form dynamically, with different descriptions and types of data.

My original idea was to create following hierarchy, keep List of `IInputModel` items in Model and generate the partial view for each one:

```
public interface IInputModel
{
        string Description { get; set; }
}

public interface IInputModel<T> : IInputModel
{
    T Value { get; set; }
}

public class InputModelBase<T> : IInputModel<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class SingleLineTextInputModel : InputModelBase<string>
{
}
```

Here is the example of my partial view:

```
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal
@model WebTranslator.Models.InputModels.SingleLineTextInputModel

<div>
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">@Model.Description</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Value" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Value" class="text-danger" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, I noticed that Asp.Net Core does not include Html.Action() helper which could allow binding my `IInputModel` to the certain type of partial view in the controller, and I don't want to write something like `switch` in my view.

The question is how to render partial views for my dynamic data in the main view (and then submit inputted data to the form)? Or maybe there are other ways to implement dynamic data input?

Comment: If you `Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Value)`, MVC will attempt to locate the template based on the type stored in T.  So if T is a DateTime it will attempt to use the `datetime.cshtml` template.

Comment: As for the request, you'll have to write your own [Model Binder to bind the value back to there respective types](http://intellitect.com/custom-model-binding-in-asp-net-core-1-0/).

Comment: @Eric, thanks a lot for your suggestion, this helped a lot. However, there is one more problem: my controller's action accepts only `Int64` parameter, so, `IModelBinderProvider.GetBinder(...)` is invoked only for `Int64` type – I can not bind my `IInputModel` instances to proper tempates.
Do you have any suggestions regarding this issue?